# Trying to Return First non-blank cell relative to row and column references (INDEX MATCH?)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to pull the first non-blank 'location' associated with each id and place that in the "initial location" column. Right now, I just have ID and Location, I am trying to create the Initial Location column below. Can I do this with an Index Match of some kind?

Here is a simplified version of the spreadsheet that I am working with:

[image: example table]

I would like to pull the "Location" with reference to the ID and put as "Initial Location". As you can see, the ID numbers are on there multiple times, and sometimes the first corresponding variable cell in Location is blank. What type of formula can be created that will reference ID 1 (for example) and pull the first non-blank Location attached to ID 1 (which would be "20" in this case) and put that in the "Initial Location" column?
I tried using an Index function but it is not working for me. Here is what I attempted to use in the initial location column:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,MIN(IF(($C1:C39)*(B1:B39<>""),ROW(A1:A39)))),"No Match")
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: would a simple IF work: `=IF(AND(B2<>"",SUMIFS($C$1:C1,$A$1:A1,A2)=0),B2,"")`?

Comment: @ScottCraner Why don't you post that as an answer? It explicitly says in the comment placeholder text "Avoid answering questions in comments."

Comment: @teylyn on this one I am not sure that would solve the problem being asked. It is the reason it is a question. Though it satisfies the picture, I have reservations as to if it would solve the larger problem. I was hoping for feed back.

Answer (score 1):

*I would like to suggest two possible methods:*

**Method 1:**

[image]

- Formula in Cell `C81`:

  ```
  =IF(AND(COUNTIFS($A$81:A81,A81,$B$81:B81,"<>0")=1),INDEX(B81:B88,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((B81:B88<>0),0),0)),"")
  ```

*Fill the formula down.*

**Method 2 (Summary Style):**

[image]

- Put IDs (works as Criteria) in range `D81:D83`.
- Array (CSE) formula in Cell `E81`, finish with **C**trl+**S**hift+**E**nter and fill down.

  ```
  =IFERROR(INDEX(B$81:B$88,MATCH(1,($D81 = $A$81:$A$88)*(B$81:B$88<>""),0)),"")
  ```

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIFS($A$2:A2,A2,$B$2:B2,">0")=1,(B2<>"")),B2,"")
```

[image]